# DeleteDuplicates while retaining sublist structure

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica, filtering

I want to DeleteDuplicates from a list of lists keeping the sublist structure intact.

E.g.

`{{1, 7, 8}, {4, 3}, {4, 1, 9}, {9, 2}}`

becomes

`{{1, 7, 8}, {4, 3}, {9}, {2}}`

This is the extent of nesting, and empty sublists are ok.

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange.  Nice first question.  You may also want to know about the Mathematica (beta) site: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a classic trick:

```
list = {{1, 7, 8}, {4, 3}, {4, 1, 9}, {9, 2}}

Module[{f},
 f[x_] := (f[x] = Sequence[]; x);
 Map[f, list, {2}]
]
```

To understand how it works, consider what happens when `f[1]` is evaluated for the first time.   `f[1]` will evaluate to `(f[1]=Sequence[]); 1`, then to just `1`.  So now a definitions has been made for `f[1]`.  The next time `f[1]` is evaluated, it will simply evaluate to `Sequence[]`.

So, the first time `f` is evaluated for an argument, it returns that argument.  The second (or third, etc.) time it is evaluated, it returns [`Sequence[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sequence.html).  `Sequence[]` has the property that it will get stripped out of expressions completely, i.e. `{1, Sequence[], 3}` will evaluate to `{1, 3}`.

To summarize, what the function does is: the first time it sees an element, it replaces the element with itself (leaves it alone).  The second time it sees the same element, it removes it.  I mapped this function at "[level 2](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SomeGeneralNotationsAndConventions.html#SA.3.6)", so it will act only on the elements of sublists.

Comment: @Szabolics Thanks, when I was trying to attack this I did come across some code that indicated `Sequence[]` might be useful. I will try to unpack this... any pedagogical comments on the way it works appreciated!

Comment: @David the idea to to use a function, `f` that acts like `Identity` but simultaneously redefines itself for that specific expression to `Sequence[]`, so that if it is called again for that expression it collapses (is removed from the list).  See [this page from the v4.0 documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v4/RefGuide/Union_ex.html) for the origin of the function (AFAIK).

Comment: @stackexchange.michael and Mr.Wizard Yep, I saw this trick in a pre-6 version of the documentation!

Comment: Yes, your explanation helps. First time I see this. Nice.

Comment: @Szabolcs & Mr. Wizard. Aha! all is clear now, thanks. This is exactly the sort of thing I expected to happen when I (naively) typed `DeleteDuplicates[list, {2}]`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Complement` for this and the only thing you have to do is, you have to store all elements you have already seen. At the beginning the list of all seen elements `a` is empty and then you add step by step all numbers which are in the sublists. This cumulated list is used in every step to delete all numbers which have already been seen:

```
DeleteDuplicatesList[l_List] :=
  Block[{a = {}},
   Table[With[{b = a},
     a = Union[a, c];
     Complement[c, b]], {c, l}]
   ];

l = {{1, 7, 8}, {4, 3}, {4, 1, 9}, {9, 2}};
DeleteDuplicatesList[l]
```

Comment: Thank you, I like the approach of using `Complement`. Although it is not obvious from the way I stated the initial problem, there is a set-theoretic background to all this.

Answer (score 2):

It's not elegant but it gets the job done:

```
t = {{1, 7, 8}, {4, 3}, {4, 1, 9}, {9, 2}}; 

Delete[t, Flatten[Rest[Position[t, #]] & /@ (DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[t]]), 1]]
```

`DeleteDuplicates`...will return the set, not multi-set, of numbers in t.
`Rest[Position[`...will return the positions of duplicates.
`Delete` removes said duplicates.